# How to change directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

How to change directory from: articles/article.php to: articles/article/ (without filename)
Is it directory with hidden index.php or something else?
I think it's related with .htaccess but I'm not sure. How can I do this?

Comment: Google "mod rewrite htaccess" - 1st result > http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/ - one of *About 304,000 results (0.30 seconds)*

Comment: If you're using a framework like Zend or Code Igniter, most have a way of customizing routes.

Comment: It's seems you're looking for URL Rewriting, maybe helpful if checking This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/3878932

Comment: You may want to make your title a little more descriptive. Also, all five of the tags/keywords you chose have nothing to do with what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess to remove the file extensions as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Where it says .php change that to your file extension. Keep in mind that for example if your file is about.php and you have a folder called "about", it won't work.

The route I see most people use is to have a huge directory of folders and index pages, that will work just fine, however search engines will have a hard time indexing your site.

This is a really popular question, probably didn't need to come here to ask haha

Answer (score 0):

## **Option 1 - Mod rewrite htaccess**

You're probably looking for [mod rewrite with an htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained). With this, you can point these types of URL's:

```
mydomain.com/articles/article/1001
mydomain.com/articles/1001
mydomain.com/1001
```

to this:

```
mydomain.com/articles/article.php?id=1001
```

## **Option 2 - Using index.php**

Alternatively, you can create a sub-directory in `articles` called `article` and rename `article.php` to `index.php` - this will allow you to use the following:

```
mydomain.com/articles/article
```

## **Option 3 - Hide PHP extensions**

Or turn off PHP file extensions in PHP configuration file, which would also give you:

```
mydomain.com/articles/article
```